# Calculator in vbs for ASP site

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I have the following problem, I'm working on a small calculator embedded in an asp, and I'm trying to make an error handler using an if, it should check if a user entered a numeric value or not. When a numeric value it shall pass and calculate the value, if it's not numeric it should set the value as zero, but in the output, should be printed "Not numeric value". But it calculates with the Zero. The Setting of the Zero is important if it is not set, I get a response the response flush. No worrying please, due to work-related reasons my variables are in german, **Ergebnis** means *result*, and **Zahl** is *number*.

Here is my code

```
l_zahl1 = request.querystring("f_zahl1")
l_zahl2 = request.querystring("f_zahl2")
l_operator = request.querystring("f_operator")

if isnumeric(request.querystring("f_zahl1")) 
then
    l_zahl1  = cint(request.querystring("f_zahl1"))
else
    l_ergebnis = "Die Angabe ist nicht numerisch"
    l_zahl1 = 0
end if
```

that's my if for the first number, the one for the second number is the same.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: When there is a non numeric, it still calulates with the Zero, instead of printing "non numeric value" (in german). What shall i do that it shows my error message instead of calcutlating with 0?

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore, solved it myself